# Exclusion Restriction for Inverse Propensity Score Weighted Regression

Tags: propensity-scores

I have been told that when fitting an inverse propensity score weighted regression 1) every control in the regression model should be used in the model estimating the propensity score, and 2) there should be at least one variable in the propensity score model that is not included in the regression model. Statement 1 was presented to me as a convention but not a necessity. Statement 2 was presented to me as a necessity.

Are these two statements correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a good idea to use every control in the regression model that you used in developing the propensity model.  This is called doubly-robust estimation.  You do not include your outcome variable in the development of the regression model.  It is used as the independent variable in the regression model, but would not appear in the propensity score model.